# Bootstrap icon in ajaxButton created by Yii

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

Is there any way how to create ajaxButton with bootstrap icon in Yii?

Answer (score 1):

I've found answer [here](http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/#tbButton)

```
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
                 'buttonType' => 'ajaxButton',
                 'label' => 'Label Here',
                 'type' => 'danger',
                 'icon' => 'play white',
                 ...
                 'ajaxOptions' => array(
                     'success' => '...',
                     'error' => '...',
                     'beforeSend' => '...',
                 )
             ));
```